# Bower points to wrong path (jQuery-form-validator)

Tags: javascript, jquery, gruntjs, bower

I just installed the [jQuery-form-validator](http://formvalidator.net/) in my project using `bower install jquery-form-validator --save` and then I ran `grunt wiredep`.

The package was correctly added to `bower_components` and to the `bower.json` file, but in the generated HTML, it points to the wrong directory.

`Grunt wiredep` added the following line:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery-form-validator/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
```

while it should be:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery-form-validator/form-validator/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
```

What is the best way to fix this? Should I just manually place the files in the right directory or can I configure something in Bower to make it point to the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the main property of jquery-form-validator [bower.json](https://github.com/victorjonsson/jQuery-Form-Validator/blob/master/bower.json) - it is pointing at the wrong path:

```
"main": "jquery.form-validator.min.js",
```

This is later used by wiredep to locate the main .js file and hence the wrong src path.
You can solve this by overriding the main property of jquery-form-validator as described [here](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep#bower-overrides). Add the following to your bower.json file:

```
"overrides": {
    "jquery-form-validator": {
      "main": "form-validator/jquery.form-validator.min.js"
    }
  }
```

It can also be a good idea to notify the jquery-form-validator about the main property.